# Delete local "remote branch" without deleting remote branch?

Tags: git

So there is a branch on my remote called feature1. I attempted to create a local branch tracking this via:

```
git checkout -b origin/feature1
```

But now `git branch` shows me this:

```
master    
*origin/feature1
```

And I know this isn't right. It should just be `feature1` locally, not `origin/feature1`.

How do I remove this while leaving the remote branch intact, and get it set up right? What did I do wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your command should have been:

```
git checkout -b feature1 origin/feature1
```

Which says 'Checkout and create branch `feature1`, and have it track `origin/feature1`'. What you did was create a branch literally named `origin/feature1`, which is not tracking any remote branch.

To fix it, swap to another branch:

```
git checkout master
```

And then delete it:

```
git branch -d origin/feature1
```

Comment: OH right `git branch -d etc` doesn't delete remote branches. Totally forgot.

Comment: Problem....`git branch -d origin/fea` is not autofilling that branch name though....

Comment: @Aerovistae I had that issue too, perhaps git is confused with the naming (and looking at local remotes). However, manually writing it does work (tested locally before answering).

Comment: Confirmed! Works. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

to list all branches

```
git branch
```

**-d/-D**

***delete a branch locally..***

```
git branch -d branchName
```

***delete a branch regardless of merge status***

```
git branch -D branchName
```

***delete a remote branch***

```
git push origin --delete branchName
```

**-d flag**:

this will delete the local branch. but it'll account git status. ie, you have to commit all your changes first.

**-D flag:**

this is enforce the git to delete the local branch regardless of the current changes you have'nt staged or commited. basically it'll do both

```
--delete --force
```

**push --delete:**

to delete a remote branch you can't use branch(when using -d/-D flag you are using it with **branch** command). You need to push it instead including the remote name(origin in this case).

to fetch the origin name, run

```
git remote
```

Answer (score 2):

What you have done here is create an ordinary local branch named `origin/feature1`.  Git is perfectly happy with this—internally, its name is `refs/heads/origin/feature1` which clearly marks it as an ordinary local branch—even though it's terribly confusing to users, who see it as looking like a remote-tracking branch.

As [Rob already answered](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36143133/1256452), you can simply delete the local branch with the bogus name.  Alternatively, you can rename it, which avoids having to get off it first:

```
$ git branch
  master
* origin/feature1
$ git branch -m feature1
$ git branch
  master
* feature1
```

Note that actual remote branches have full internal names that start with `refs/remotes/`, and you can run `git symbolic-ref HEAD` to see the full internal name of the current branch (which may be less confusing, provided you know about the `refs/heads/` vs `refs/remotes/` thing).

Answer (score 1):

To delete a branch its as simple as that:

```
git branch -D <branch name>
```

But you can also just rename the old one:

> And I know this isn't right. It should just be feature1 locally, not origin/feature1.

```
git branch -m <new_name>
```

Here is a full screenshot of all the commands

[image]