# Delete local "remote branch" after the branch was deleted locally and remotely

Tags: git, github

This is *not* a duplicate of [How do I delete a Git branch both locally and remotely?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2003505/how-do-i-delete-a-git-branch-both-locally-and-remotely), and I've read [Delete local “remote branch” without deleting remote branch?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36143098/delete-local-remote-branch-without-deleting-remote-branch) but get little help.

There was a branch called `stats_dev` before. After merging it to `master` and deleting it on GitHub, I did `git branch -d stats_dev` so `stats_dev` branch is gone remotely and locally.

However, now I do `git branch -a` and I find the list pasted below:

```
* master
remotes/origin/HEAD -> origin/master
remotes/origin/master
remotes/origin/stats_dev
```

It seems that `remotes/origin/stats_dev` still somehow exists. I try `git branch -d remotes/origin/stats_dev` and `git branch -d origin/stats_dev`, but error messages like `error: branch 'origin/stats_dev' not found.` are returned. How can I get rid of `remotes/origin/stats_dev`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A [`git fetch --all --prune`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-fetch#git-fetch--p) should get rid of what is effectively a pointer (a remote tracking branch tracking what the remote branch was referring to)

See [`git fetch`: PRUNING](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-fetch#_pruning).

[smarber](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1507546/smarber) mentions the alternative [`git remote` command](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-remote.html#git-remote-emupdateem):

```
git remote update -p
```

Comment: I would suggest, `git fetch --all --prune`.

Comment: @MarufTuhin Good point. I have edited the answer accordingly.

Comment: `git remote update -p` works as well :D

Comment: @smarber Thank you. I have included your comment in the answer for more visibility.